# Kendo grid - auto size columns to width of header captions, not the width of the column data?

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

Anybody know how to make the Kendo grid auto size columns to width of *header captions*, rather than the width of the column data?

I am using the Razor Grid helper to set up my grid.